# One-forms and infinitesmally small distances

Tags: integration, physics, differential-forms

I have recently been studying a bit of differential geometry and have become somewhat familiar with integrating volume forms. In physics (and also maths) often times, we say things like $dx$ is an infinitesimally small distance, and that as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ we end up with $dx$. I was wondering what the link between $dx$ being a one-form and $dx$ being an infinitesimally small distance is. Thank you!

Comment: This was discussed over at Physics.SE in this old question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92925/how-to-treat-differentials-and-infinitesimals. (Whether the answers are satisfactory is another question entirely.)

Comment: Mathematicians rarely speak of infinitesimals unless they're doing non-standard analysis. But it's just in a word (well, two) about *linear approximations* ... "infinitesimally" tangent spaces are good approximations to manifolds.